# VirtualBox не создаёт новую виртуальную машину.

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, linux

Пытаюсь создать виртуалку с win 98 но VB не желает этого делать говорит:

> Не удалось создать директорию машиныwin98 в родительском каталоге/home/alexandr/VirtualBox VMs.
>
> Пожалуйста, проверьте фактсуществования родительского каталога иналичие у Вас доступа для создания внём папок и файлов.

Проверил права:

> drwxrwxrwx   6 alexander alexander  4096 окт.   5 11:53 VirtualBox VMs

пользователь alexander входит в группу vboxusers

**РЕШЕНИЕ:Запускаем virtualbox лезем в меню файл/свойства/общие/ папка для машин -> указываем папку к которой есть доступ у текущего пользователя**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не занаю как у Вас, а у меня пользователь входит в группу vboxusers, пока этого не сделать, машина не создается (OpenSUSE)

Comment: у меня тоже, я дополнил вопрос.

Comment: Меня одного смущает /home/**alexandr**/ и alexand**e**r ?

Comment: ну это скорее всего опечатка. а по существу, надо изучать /var/log

Comment: Скорее всего что нет, так как все copypaste. А зачем изучать каталог?

Comment: Изучать на предмет файлов содержащих слова vbox и (или) virtualbox, поможет расследованию.

Comment: подумал и пришёл к выводу, что необходимо поменять путь на родительский каталог, чтобы он стал таким: /home/alexandеr/VirtualBox VMs.вот только как это сделать? пока буду сам рыть, но и от помощи не откажусь :)

Comment: Нашёл решение, обновил вопрос. Всем спасибо!